# ASP.NET Core - change form action to list options in view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have controller for changing website language, saving cookie and returning url.

`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Website.Controllers;
public class CultureController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365) }
        );
        
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

`

And in View I need create html list for better user experience but I don't understand how to change from 'form' to 'list' or how to submit changes and return url
`

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocalizationOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();

    var cultureItems = LocalizationOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.EnglishName })
        .ToList();

    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}{Context.Request.QueryString}";
}

<!-- FROM FORM -->
<div class="language">
    <form asp-controller="Culture" asp-action="SetCulture" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" class="form-horizontal nav-link text-dark">
        <select name="culture"
                onchange="this.form.submit();"
                asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name"
                asp-items="cultureItems">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- TO LIST -->

<div class="language-toggle">
    <a href="#" class="toggle-btn"><i class="fas fa-language"></i></a>
        <ul class="language-menu">
        @foreach (var item in LocalizationOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures)
        {
            <li><a href="#?HOW">@item.Name.ToUpper()</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

`

I tried with anchor tag helper but without success

output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGNp.png)

I can get current url in view and append ?culture=en and that changes language and stays on current page but does not save cookie so every time user goes to different page website is in native language not in user selected language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitCulForm(val) {
            document.getElementById("cultureVal").value = val;
            var hh = document.getElementById("cultureForm");            
            hh.submit();
           
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Then

```
    <form asp-controller="Culture" id="cultureForm" asp-action="SetCulture" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" class="form-horizontal nav-link text-dark">
      <input id="cultureVal" type="hidden" name="culture" value="-">
        <div class="language-toggle">
            <a href="#" class="toggle-btn"><i class="fas fa-language"></i></a>
                <ul class="language-menu">
                @foreach (var item in LocalizationOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures)
                {
                    <li><a href="#" id="submit-link" name="culture" class="button" onclick="return submitCulForm('@item.Value')">@item.Name.ToUpper()</a></li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working now, I only had to change submitCulForm('@item.Value') to submitCulForm('@item.Name')

Answer (score 0):

If you try to pass the value with herf,you shouldn't add `[HttpPost]` Attribute on  your controller.

I tried with the codes in your controller,it works well,I'll show what I've tried and hopes it could help

in View:

```
<div>
    <a asp-action="SetCulture" asp-route-culture="zh-CN">zh-CN</a>
    <a asp-action="SetCulture" asp-route-culture="en-US">en-US</a>
</div>

<script>
    var cookie = document.cookie
    console.log(cookie)
</script>
```

in Controller:

```
public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
        {
            if (culture != null)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365) });

                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Configure in startup:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(
                options =>
                {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                        factory.Create(typeof(SharedResources));
                });

 ...............

var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "zh-CN" };
            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
                
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

created an empty class called SharedResources

and the resourcefile:

[image]

The Result:

[image]

It just performed as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookierequestcultureprovider),and if you tried with mulipule providers,you could try to change request culture providers order which has been mentioned in the document

Comment: Thanks @Ruikai but this is to complicated for me to implement